# Vue.js: How to include HTML file programmatically?

Tags: vue.js

I am new to vue.js. 
I am using the following command to include an html file

```
     <?php  include("templates/property.html");  ?>
```

This html file contains regular httml tags as well as vue data, e.g. {{name}}}. Can I include this file programatically in a div element in the click event of an element?

Comment: yes, any problem ??

Comment: HTML you insert will not be managed by Vue.

Comment: I don't think it's a good idea to mix PHP and Vue together like this.  Make a Vue component that uses that template, instead of trying to stuff it in with PHP.

Comment: rashidnk: This works, but when one html includes the second and the second includes third, sometimes vue data is not available in those files.